# PHP: Param count and argument count don't match

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2005

My php application is using the MS SQLSrv driver.   When making a call to a stored procedure in my database, I get the following error after running sqlsrv_execute(): **param count and argument count don't match**.  My Code is as follows:

```
    $sql = "{call myStoredProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";

    //Passing by reference instead of value, otherwise sqlsrv_prepare is not happy
    $params = array(array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array(&$param2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array(&$param3, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array(&$param4, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array(&$param5, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array(&$param6, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
                    );

    /* Create the statement. */
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $params);
    if( $stmt )
    {
         echo "Statement prepared.\n";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Error in preparing statement.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    //TODO: Resolve error, "param count and argument count don't match"
    $stmt = sqlsrv_execute($conn, $sql, $params);

    //This statement will run, but no rows are returned and rowCount is false.
    //$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

    $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
    $numFields = sqlsrv_num_fields( $stmt );

    //Rest of code...
```

I've spent an hour on this and combed through PHP.Net and Microsoft documentation.  Has anyone else encountered a similar error?  Any help is appreciated.

And yes, I've checked my param count, my stored procedure takes 6 parameters.

UPDATE:

Stored procedure snippet:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure] 
    @param1 VARCHAR(64),
    @param2 VARCHAR(64),
    @param3 DATETIME, 
    @param4 DATETIME,
    @param5 INT = 9,
    @param6 INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

//Do stuff 

END
```

Comment: Can you post some information on the actual stored procedure?

Comment: Wild guess, because I'm far from being an expert, but since the last param is an output parameter, I don't see why it should be bound: the stored proc won't do anything with the given value.

Comment: Unfortunately, from what I've read on Microsoft's docs, you have to provide all parameters, input, output and both bi-directional in/out.

Comment: I'm no expert either, but in the example here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296181.aspx ), the parameters are passed to sqlsrv_prepare, and the return value ($stmt) is then executed (in your code, you execute using $sql and $params again). Oversight or by design?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SQLSRV_EXECUTE` incorrectely. The error that your are getting is actually a PHP error, telling you that you are passing the wrong parameters to `SQLSRV_EXECUTE`.

Defined as:
[sqlsrv_execute(resource $stmt)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296162%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
But you are calling: `sqlsrv_execute($conn, $sql, $params)`

I've fixed up the code below, assuming the stored procedure is setup properly. Let me know if it works.

```
$sql = "{call myStoredProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";

//Passing by reference instead of value, otherwise sqlsrv_prepare is not happy
$params = array(array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$param2, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$param3, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$param4, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$param5, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$param6, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
                );

/* Create the statement. */
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt )
{
     echo "Statement prepared.\n";
}
else
{
     echo "Error in preparing statement.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

//Shouldn't assign this to $stmt, $stmt can be reused for multiple sqlsrv_execute() calls
$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

if($result === false)
{
    //Error handling
}
else
{
    $rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows( $result );
    $numFields = sqlsrv_num_fields( $result );
}
```

Comment: Also, note the change "$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);"  Part of the point of the prepare / execute strategy here is that you can change the variables assigned above and just execute it again for a new result.

Comment: Thank your for this answer. I was struggling for over an hour to get prepared statements to work. PS: Make sure the DB User has "EXECUTE" privileges on th stored procedure ;)